# selenium grid - best option?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-grid

My team has a new Asp.net MVC intranet app.
I have been doing some research on using selenium + selenium grid.
However I'm seeing that the project is not being maintained.

As of today, with a brand new app, is this best (and free) option for doing automated testing on a local intranet app? I need to use a Windows 2008 box to host this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium is being maintained actively (can't speak of grid though).
apropos of your app, if it is web and does not have custom control then you might like to try selenium.

Answer (score 1):

If Selenium Grid isn't being maintained, that's news to me, since I'm the guy maintaining it and have been for over a year :-)  Where did you see that it's not being maintained?